# iOS 5: Set min and max value of input type="date"

Tags: iphone, date, types, input, ios5

I'm trying to figure out how to set the min and the max value of an `input type="date"`.
I couldn't find anything on the web and didn't figure it out by myself.

I need to set the min and max values to verify the age.
I thought it might be something like `<input type="date" min="1900-01-01" max="(year-18)-day(this month)-month(this month)">`.

Another thing is that I wanted to set the value so that the selectbox is not empty.

A link would be enough. Maybe I was searching for the wrong words.

Answer (score 3):

You need to have

```
value="2012-01-01"
```

in that format ( %Y-%m-%d ) to have the value show in the field and in the picker.

The HTML5 spec allows for max and min attributes, but Mobile Safari doesn't support it. pity.

Comment: Is this still true? Does mobile Safari not support this in late 2019 with iOS 13?