# How to block(disable) selecting future date in type="date".in query mobile?

Tags: jquery-mobile

can you please tell me how to  block selecting future date in type="date".in query mobile? 
i have button (+) on header .on clicking i open a pop up screen .There is a date field .i need to block or hidden future date in date picker(type="date").

here is fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/7JqRG/6/

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#Home', function(){ 
    $(document).on( "popupafteropen", "#CaseInformationScreen",function( event, ui ) {
        var now = new Date();

        var day = ("0" + now.getDate()).slice(-2);
        var month = ("0" + (now.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);

        var today = now.getFullYear()+"-"+(month)+"-"+(day) ;

        $('#caseDate').val(today);    
    });        
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/7JqRG/9/

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#Home', function(){ 
    $(document).on( "popupafteropen", "#CaseInformationScreen",function( event, ui ) {
        var now = new Date();

        var day = ("0" + now.getDate()).slice(-2);
        var month = ("0" + (now.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);

        var today = now.getFullYear()+"-"+(month)+"-"+(day) ;

        $('#caseDate').attr('max', today);
        $('#caseDate').val(today);    
    });        
});
```

Reference documentation: http://html5doctor.com/html5-forms-input-types/

Unfortunately because max and min don't work on iOS here's also a javascript solution to this problem: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/7JqRG/10/

```
var dateControler = {
    currentDate : null
}

$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#Home', function(){ 
    $(document).on( "popupafteropen", "#CaseInformationScreen",function( event, ui ) {
        var now = new Date();

        var day = ("0" + now.getDate()).slice(-2);
        var month = ("0" + (now.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);

        var today = now.getFullYear()+"-"+(month)+"-"+(day) ;
        $('#caseDate').val(today);
        dateControler.currentDate = today;
    });        
    $(document).on( "change", "#caseDate",function( event, ui ) {
        var now = new Date();
        var selectedDate = new Date($(this).val());
        if(selectedDate > now) {
            $(this).val(dateControler.currentDate)
        } else {
            dateControler.currentDate = $(this).val();
        }
    });    
});
```

Comment: Damn, apparently iOs dont support max and min: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8491198/ios-5-set-min-and-max-value-of-input-type-date , I will create you a javascript solution for this problem.

Comment: so any other solution on ios..?

Comment: I will write you a javascript solution.

Comment: Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/7JqRG/10/ test it and tell me is it ok, I have tested it on desktop browser and Android phone.

Answer (score 1):

We can set the "max" and "min" date for date input type, using attribute to hidden future date.

```
    $('#caseDate').attr("max",today);
    $('#caseDate').attr("min",today);
```

Answer (score 1):

We can set max and min attributes in input type and assign the date in ISO format (e.g. `2010-08-14`), first the year with four digits, then the month and in the last position the day of month.

```
<input type="date" min="2010-08-14" max="2011-08-14" value="2010-08-14"/>
```

**Please note:**

- The month and the days must always be written with two digits (e.g. 01 for january and not simply 1)
- It works on Android only